# How can I remove points that are too close to each other using Shapely?

Tags: python, shapely

I've got the following code:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
xs = range(10)
ys = range(10)
points = [Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(x, y)]
line = LineString(points)
```

Now I want to edit points such that if the two adjacent points are close than `MIN_DISTANCE`, then I want to remove the latter one:
i.e., from `line=[(1, 1), (1.1, 1.1), (3, 3)], MIN_DISTANCE=2` I'd get `line=[(1, 1), (3, 3)]`.

Is it OK to write a bruteforce solution (i.e., `for point in line`) and overwrite the points in line or is there a built in function instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `simplify` method to achieve that:

```
new_line = line.simplify(tolerance=MIN_DISTANCE)
```

with your example it would be:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
xs = range(10)
ys = range(10)
x, y = zip(*[(1, 1), (1.1, 1.1), (3, 3)])
points = [Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(x, y)]
line = LineString(points)

MIN_DISTANCE = 2
new_line = line.simplify(tolerance=MIN_DISTANCE)

print(f"Original coordinates: {line.xy}")
print(f"Simplified coordinates: {new_line.xy}")


# Original coordinates: (array('d', [1.0, 1.1, 3.0]), array('d', [1.0, 1.1, 3.0]))
# Simplified coordinates: (array('d', [1.0, 3.0]), array('d', [1.0, 3.0]))
```